# Store front Main Menu Link not working showing 404 error

Tags: virtocommerce

My storefront main menu links points to 404 error. All the categories and products are listed in landing page and is able to select all products and categories, but when i click any links in main menu it points to 404 error. i had tried many ways changing the link list in CMS but failed to sort out this issue.

My Admin Content Setting for links

Admin CMS Main menu Link list
[image]

Admin CMS Sub menu Links list 1:

[image]

Admin CMS Submenu Link list 2:

[image]

Storefront Landing page:

[image]

Storefront Main menu link page, which is showing 404 error when i clicked headphone link.

[image: Error page storefront]

I had pointed SEO URL in my setting.

Comment: Please check that your store is assigned to Electronics catalog

Answer (score 1):

You should check the search engine. Is search provider configured, Category index up to date?

[image: Index build UI]

Also, what's the index value available in (e.g. headphones) category details view?

Comment: Yes i had checked it is lucene Details of Search Engine

Details of SEO url is attached in answer section

Bread crumb showing wrong path it seems. @eMazeika

Answer (score 0):

Yes i had checked it is lucene [Details of Search Engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuM6F.jpg)

Also iam attaching my SEO details 
[SEO url details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvMYh.jpg)

Bread crumb showing wrong path it seems
[Wrong breadcrumb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJhys.jpg)

Comment: Please check that your store is assigned to Electronics catalog